# OpenGl handling lots of vertexes

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d

I have code for rendering models, but if I use too many vertices I meet a problem: program cant allocate memory enough to handle all vertices.

```
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
 glVertexPointer(3,GL_FLOAT,0,VertexArray);
 glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT,0,NormalArray);
 glColorPointer(3,GL_FLOAT,0,ColorArray);
```

Here is my code, its just a part of it, but I think enough. VertexArray is got by using new operator, it is a pointer on an array. But if I use array of length, e.g. 10000000 values I get an error.

Is there any way to allocate memory from different parts of RAM? Or any other way to find a solution?

Comment: Where do these arrays come from?

Comment: @nicol-bolas from voxel octtree. it is cubes vertices

Comment: I meant more *generally* where they come from. Show us the declarations of them. If you're allocating them on the heap, let's see those allocations. Also, what kind of error do you get and where do you get it? Exactly what error is it? Give us a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're drawing models that wont be modified often after their first call you could switch to using [VBOs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_Buffer_Object) and use the STATIC_DRAW flag, this will most likely tell your GPU to put them in video memory, you'll have more breathing room memory wise if you move to using some VBOs for models that you don't need to keep changing/have all the vertex data readily accessible on your CPU. (Even if not there are ways to access this vertex data and update, such as glBufferSubData, and using the DYNAMIC_DRAW flag instead).

VBOs are stored in GPU memory, not system meory, giving you much more capacity before you start hitting a memory cap.

The old glVertexPointer method doesn't have this benefit.

Comment: Sorry, dont get it. "VBOs are stored in GPU memory, not system meory, giving you much more capacity". Whaaat? GPU memory is bigger then RAM? It is not true...

Comment: and btw I'm writing voxel editor (3d models editor), so my objects are changing.

Comment: No, but you don't have to keep the vertex information for those objects in RAM, you need only store some information about where the models are on the GPU (a VAO). You can generate Vertex Buffer Objects (to store all of your model information, vertex positions, normals, tex-coords, anything per vertex can be described using a Vertex Attrib Pointer) and you can call to draw the model using glDrawArrays or glDrawElements rather than needing to call glVertexPointer, with a pointer to some array of vertex positions stored on RAM.

Comment: Look at using VBO and VAOs like in the link I referenced and you'll save a lot of memory. You can also further reduce the amount of memory needed if you have a repetitive object that is drawn many times (i.e a 'cube' if you're doing a voxel editor) by utilising instancing. So then you'll just need to store one 'cube' object in GPU memory, and you can just store the co-ordinates or origin for many instances of it. This will save you huge amounts of memory that you're currently having to use to store all the vertex positions on system memory/RAM.